# Accessing model from controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to get data from my database and then in my model I wish to do some php stuff to the data before passing it to my view.

Normally I would do this to get all of my data:

```
->with('content', Content::all());
```

But I have set up a function in my model called test:

```
public function test(){

 //get and modify data here
}
```

How can I access this using:

```
->with
```

from my controller?

Comment: If you made this 'test' function static , would it work with you? , cuz its working with me but i dont get ur example..

Comment: Can you please provide a more in depth description of what you are trying to do? Maybe `with()` is not the best way to do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the one you are looking for?

Model:

```
public static function foo($bar) {
    return static::where('foo', '=', 'bar');
}
```

Controller:

```
->with('content', Foo::foo("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't really explained correctly but I'll try to answer anyway.

From what I understand, you want to do some data transformation in the model before it is used. But your comment in the test() function say that you want to GET and modify data.

In laravel, functions for getting and modifying data are separated:

For getting data, you can define a query scope ( http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes ). A query scope is usually a shortand for adding some parameters to an existing query.

For modifying data before it is read from the model, or before assinging it to the model, Eloquent provide a system called mutators (http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators ). A mutator is a method called when reading or assiging value to a field. It is usualy to convert php type to a database type (for example array to json on save, then json to array on read). A mutator can be used to populate some extra value or do some extra checks to the value.

I hope I've helped you a bit. If you don't find it is a correct answer, please clarify your question so I can help you a little more.

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful. I'm wondering how I would call the model from the controller? And call the method I write in the model?

Comment: What about reading the documentation? http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage